# Can you construct a $8*8$ table each of its entries are $1,2,...8^2$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Can you construct a $8*8$ table each of its entries are $1,2,...8^2$ without any repitition in such a way the product of the entries in any $8$ dispersed squares always gives the same remainder modulo $65$.

Ok, what if the table was $10*10$? and it is required to check modulo $101$ with elements $1,2,...10^2$?

Two Squares are said to be 'dispersed' if they are not in the same row or same column.

My Idea was to place an element and its inverse modulo $65$ in the dispersed squares so that their product is $1$ modulo $65$. But there are quite a few elements like $5,10,15$ whose inverses do not exist and moreover some are self inverses.Can anyone give a valid construction?

Comment: Please check the case for $10*10$ modulo $101$

Comment: Since $101$ is prime, it is possible.  Details below.

Answer (score 1):

$13$ divides $65$, and there are only four entries divisible by $13$.  Any $8$ dispersed squares avoiding those four will have a product not divisible by $13$.  So...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a construction for the case when $p = n^2+1$ is prime, e.g. when $n=10$.  A necessary and sufficient condition then (for the products of "dispersed squares" of $n\times n$ matrix $M$ to be equal mod $p$) is that all $2\times 2$ submatrices be singular mod $p$.

To see this, consider two such products which differ only in two choices or row and column entries, say $M_{ij}$ and $M_{k\ell}$ versus $M_{i\ell}$ and $M_{kj}$.  Since all entries $1,\ldots,n^2$ are invertible mod $p$, we have:

$$ M_{ij} M_{k\ell} = M_{i\ell} M_{kj} \bmod p $$

Hence the determinant of the corresponding $2\times 2$ matrix is zero mod $p$.

But this makes the entries of the matrix $M$ very rigid.  Since the property of equal products of "dispersed squares" is preserved by permutations of the rows and columns, we can assume $M_{11} = 1$.  It follows by the above relation for $k=\ell=1$:

$$ M_{ij} = M_{i1} M_{1j} \bmod p $$

It follows that the matrix $M$ is determined by its first row and first column as a multiplication table mod $p$ in the remaining $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ entries.  Since we've assumed $p$ prime, let $r$ be [a primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) mod $p$, so that entries of $M$ are all of the form $r^a$ for distinct $a = 0,1,\ldots,n^2-1$.

This converts the multiplication table into an addition table mod $n^2$ on the primitive root exponents $a(i,j)$ such that $M_{i,j} = r^{a(i,j)}$.  Note that $a(1,1)=0$.

Thus we need first row entries $a(1,j)$ when $j=2,\ldots,n$ and first column entries $a(i,1)$ when $i=2,\ldots,n$:

$$ 1 \le a(1,j),a(i,1) \le n^2-1 \text{ when } i,j \neq 1 $$

so that the $n^2$ sums $a(i,j) = a(1,j) + a(i,1)$ are distinct mod $n^2$.

The following matrix shows this is easily done using two-place radix $n$ arithmetic, i.e. $a(i,j) = n(i-1)+ (j-1)$:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \cdots & n-1 \\
n & \ddots  & & & & & \cdots & \\
2n & & \ddots  & & & & \cdots & \\ 
3n & & & \ddots  & & &  \cdots & \\ 
\vdots & & & & & & \\
n(n-1) & & & & & & \cdots & n^2-1
\end{bmatrix} $$

In particular since $n=10$ gives $p = 101$ as a prime, the requested table can be constructed in that case.  Choosing $r=2$ as a (smallest) primitive root for $p=101$ and table $A$ as "consecutive" exponents outlined by the radix ten method, we get:

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 16 & 32 & 64 & 27 & 54 & 7 \\
14 & 28 & 56 & 11 & 22 & 44 & 88 & 75 & 49 & 98 \\
95 & 89 & 77 & 53 & 5 & 10 & 20 & 40 & 80 & 59 \\
17 & 34 & 68 & 35 & 70 & 39 & 78 & 55 & 9 & 18 \\
36 & 72 & 43 & 86 & 71 & 41 & 82 & 63 & 25 & 50 \\
100 & 99 & 97 & 93 & 85 & 69 & 37 & 74 & 47 & 94 \\
87 & 73 & 45 & 90 & 79 & 57 & 13 & 26 & 52 & 3 \\
6 & 12 & 24 & 48 & 96 & 91 & 81 & 61 & 21 & 42 \\
84 & 67 & 33 & 66 & 31 & 62 & 23 & 46 & 92 & 83 \\
65 & 29 & 58 & 15 & 30 & 60 & 19 & 38 & 76 & 51 \end{bmatrix} $$

Since the exponents from the diagonal of $A$ (or from any "dispersed squares") add up to $495=11\cdot \binom{10}{2}$, the product of corresponding entries of $M$ is always $2^{495} \equiv 2^{95} \equiv 60 \bmod{101}$.